# Are there reference manual pages anywhere for QGIS built-in "buffer" and plugin "points2one"?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, qgis-plugins, buffer

Perhaps I am missing some quick pop-up help mechanism, but as a relative newcomer to QGIS (having cut my teeth on ArcGIS 10.1), I am struggling to find reference manuals (i.e. explanations of all parameters/operations) for many of the core commands/plugins. Most of the help seems to be in the form of tutorials, which though some are remarkably well written are not in a useful format when you want to know "what does field X in this dialogue box do?"

Firstly when trying to use the built in Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Buffer tool, what does the "segments to approximate" setting actually mean? Searching the official help pages I could only comes up with the following interesting but rather discursive article:

http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html?highlight=buffer

For the Points2one plugin, I've found some quite helpful information already on StackExchange for getting it to do basically what I want, but am surprised that I'm having to scrabble round for such information long after finding the plugin itself. Does anyone know if there is manual page for it? I couldn't find anything from its homepage:

https://launchpad.net/points2one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this [QGIS wiki page](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Specify_distance_buffers) it says that:

> Segments to approximate specifies the number of segments to use to approximate a quarter of a circle.

Answer (score 3):

I was just looking for the same answer myself and while my answer is not 'official', it's based on my interpretation of this Training Manual entry I found:

http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/answers/answers.html#basic-distance-from-high-schools

I think the above illustrates the buffer segments quite well. My answer is therefore...

The `Segments to approximate` value is one which determines how many segments are used to draw each section of the buffer. I would guess that playing with values of 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20 should give you a good idea of what's going on. A higher value gives a smoother shape. I used 20 and was happy with the resulting buffer I created.

Hope that helps!